# Android Retrofit post information to api database

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit

How can I post in my case information from the android device to my api route.
Currently I do not get any response in my android monitor.

I have created a basic RetrofitBuilder class.
I have created an ApiService which contains this:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("device")
Call<DeviceResponse> device(@Field("device_name") String device_name,
                            @Field("device_producer") String device_producer,
                            @Field("device_pixel_width") int device_pixel_width,
                            @Field("device_pixel_height") int device_pixel_height,
                            @Field("device_ratio_width") int device_ratio_width,
                            @Field("device_ratio_height") int device_ratio_height,
                            @Field("device_android_version") int device_android_version,
                            @Field("device_status") int device_status);
```

A Device Model which contains a device constructor with setter and getters.

A DeviceResponse class:

```
public class DeviceResponse {

    List<Device> data;

    public List<Device> getData() {
        return data;
    }

}
```

And in my Activity I call it like this:

```
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

    tokenManager = TokenManager.getInstance(getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE));
    service = RetrofitBuilder.createServiceWithAuth(ApiService.class, tokenManager);

           Integer id = null;
            String device_name = "samsung";
            String device_producer = "apple";
            int device_pixel_width = 12312;
            int device_pixel_height = 123;
            int device_ratio_width = 12;
            int device_ratio_height = 23;
            char device_android_version = 6;
            int device_status = 1;

            call = service.device(device_name, device_producer, device_pixel_width, device_pixel_height, device_ratio_width, device_ratio_height, device_android_version, device_status);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just need to add `@POST` annotation with **EndPoint** like

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("endPoint")
Call<DeviceResponse> device(@Field("device_name") String device_name,
                        @Field("device_producer") String device_producer,
                        @Field("device_pixel_width") int device_pixel_width,
                        @Field("device_pixel_height") int device_pixel_height,
                        @Field("device_ratio_width") int device_ratio_width,
                        @Field("device_ratio_height") int device_ratio_height,
                        @Field("device_android_version") int device_android_version,
                        @Field("device_status") int device_status);
```

Check this for more info: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-send-data-form-urlencoded

Comment: sorry if I am wrong but I do have an endpoint or not? `@POST("device")`

Comment: if device is your endpoint than you should add that with @POST annotation in Retrofit

Comment: Sorry I forgot to copy that

Comment: ok it is added still no response or what excatly do you mean?

Comment: @utdev Try your API call in Postman in firefox or chrome at least once

Answer (score 0):

try adding @POST like this,

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("yourURLendpoint")
Call<DeviceResponse> device(@Field("device_name") String device_name,
                            @Field("device_producer") String device_producer,
                            @Field("device_pixel_width") int device_pixel_width,
                            @Field("device_pixel_height") int device_pixel_height,
                            @Field("device_ratio_width") int device_ratio_width,
                            @Field("device_ratio_height") int device_ratio_height,
                            @Field("device_android_version") int device_android_version,
                            @Field("device_status") int device_status);
```

Comment: ok.. whatever you have end point add that in @Post annotation

Comment: ok it is added still no response or what excatly do you mean?

Comment: I added this `@POST("device")` which I forgot to paste first, updated the question code aswell

Comment: no not in this way.. I mean to say add your end point of URL for example if it is http://example.com/water_laundry/index.php/api/user/register  add only
/water_laundry/index.php/api/user/register this much as endpoint URL

Comment: It should be fine I defined the base url in my RetrofitBuilder like this:

`http://192.168.3.105/app/public/api/`

The route for device is `http://192.168.3.105/app/public/api/device`

Comment: ha you add "/app/public/api/device" this much as a endpoint URL and "http://192.168.3.105" this is route URL